# How to display a You save % and price in woocommerce product page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Looking for a bit of help here, we have simple product in woocommerce and we want to display a you save % and amount on the product page for any discount we offer.

We have it set up for a variable product already but not for a simple product can anyone help with this.

Here is the code we have for the variable product.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'imti_variation_price_format_310', 10, 2 );
function imti_variation_price_format_310( $price, $product ) {
    // Getting the clean numeric prices (without html and currency)
    $min_var_reg_price = $product->get_variation_regular_price( 'min', true );
    $min_var_sale_price = $product->get_variation_sale_price( 'min', true );
    $price_diff = $min_var_reg_price - $min_var_sale_price ;
    $currency_symbol = get_woocommerce_currency_symbol(); 

    // Percentage calculation and text
    $percentage = round( ( $min_var_reg_price - $min_var_sale_price ) / $min_var_reg_price * 100 ).'%';
    $percentage_txt = __('<br/><p class="you-save"><small style="color:#d1461c; font-size:12.8px; font-weight:bold;"> You Save '.$percentage. ' (-&nbsp'.$currency_symbol. ''.$price_diff. ') </small></p>' , 'woocommerce' );

    return '<del>' . wc_price( $min_var_reg_price ) . '</del> <ins>' . wc_price( $min_var_sale_price ) . $percentage_txt . '</ins>';
}
```

Thanks
Jamie

Answer (score 0):

Okay. The easy way it changes your hook to `woocommerce_get_price_html`. But I want to explain the problem with your solution. I suggest to move in another way. Firstly create a function which works with product independent this is variation product or simple:

```
function discount_message( $product ) {
    $sale_price = 'variable' === $product->get_type()
        ? $product->get_variation_sale_price( 'min' )
        : $product->get_sale_price();
    $regular_price = 'variable' === $product->get_type()
        ? $product->get_variation_regular_price( 'min' )
        : $product->get_regular_price();

    $discount = round( $sale_price / $regular_price * 100 );

    echo '<p class="you-save"><small>';
    echo sprintf(
        __( 'You Save %1$s (-%2$s)', 'your-domain' ),
        absint( $discount ) . '%',
        wc_price( absint( $regular_price - $sale_price ) )
    );
    echo '</small></p>';
}
```

Then create a function that will separately from product price (or you can also use filter `woocommerce_get_price_html` but I don't like this idea):

```
function single_product_discount_message() {
    global $product;
    discount_message( $product );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'single_product_discount_message', 9 );
```

When you will add the `single_product_discount_message` to hook `woocommerce_single_product_summary` you can change priority number(9) to another to move this label on your product cart.